# Made a mistake with Git

Tags: git

We've got 3 release pending 4.0.3, 4.0.4 and 4.0.5. When I created a new branch I accidentally took it from 4.0.5 where I should have taken 4.0.4. Here is the graphic representation from TortoiseGit of this case. I've created a release_4_0_4_new branch and want to incorporate all changes from this point up into that release. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So good news first, this is totally fixable. Bad news is that at this point you need to jump out of any GUI program you are using for Source Control interaction and rely on the Git console to fix your branches.

Assuming you have already pushed the incorrect changes to your public repository, you ***shouldn't*** rebase your problem branch anymore... that has the potential to mess up every other developer's local repository.

**Fixing The Incorrect Branch**

To fix the branch you incorrectly applied your changes to in a safe manner, you should manually rollback your changes locally and then push a new "redacted code" commit. Keep in mind this shouldn't be that hard as you can directly `git checkout` the sha-1 hash ID of the commit prior to the problematic changes you applied, copy the code elsewhere, re-checkout the problem branch and then overwrite your working directory with the rolled-back code.

**Applying your Changes to the Correct Branch**

For your new branch, you can do a couple things. Assuming you have your original code, you can just checkout the branch you meant to push to and apply the changes as a new commit.

Alternatively, you might be able to play around with the [`git cherrypick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) command to grab the commits you meant to apply to the branch you meant to commit to. ***Keep in mind***, however, that because commit history builds upon previous commits, if your problematic branch contained any edits you didn't want in the correct branch, then those would come over too when cherry-picked to your correct branch. So creating a brand new commit might be the safest path to applying your changes.

Comment: I decided to create a new branch from a point I know everything is good and cherrypicked all changes. It was 2 hours of work but I'm confident everything is fine now. Thanks for the insights Dan.

Answer (score 1):

You need rebase your branch:

```bash
git checkout -f yourFeatureBranch
git rebase release-4.0.5 --onto=release-4.0.4
# if conflict appears:
git mergetool # resolve it 
git rebase --continue # to continue rebase after conflict resolution
git push --force-with-lease
```

In `git rebase` first argument points from which branch you feature barnch was started from. `--onto=` points to where your feature branch should be started from.

Comment: I normally use GitKraken for GIT stuff, which logs me in automatically, but in a command terminal I get authentication errors.

Comment: Only `git push --force-with-lease` can lead to authentication errors. But when you've reached this step, you can do push form you git Frontend UI. I'm not using GitKraken or TortoiseGit. On Windows I use GitExtenstions - great tool, but I still prefer command line, since I know exactly how it works. I use UI-frontends as visualization tools.

Comment: Is this a public branch though? Because rebasing a public branch is a cardinal sin in Git... you can end up corrupting every other users local repositories

Comment: @DanK he explain he has 3 release branches active and create new branch started from one of release branch. I think it is good assumption this is a feature branch (used only by him during development).

Comment: Fair enough but at that point I'd think it would be easier to just rollback the head commit and apply the changes as a brand new commit on the correct branch. But that's me... Rebasing always makes me uncomfortable as its so easy to nuke your history.

Comment: @DanK you never "corrupt" anything, and it's only a minor hassle unless you work with lots of people who don't know what they're doing. And, the sooner you do it, the less trouble it causes!

Comment: @hobbs I'm going to have to respectfully but firmly disagree with you. When you rebase, under the hood you are reassigning the sha-1 parent addresses contained within your commits. This fundamentally changes the history within your underlying graph and when performed on shared commits can break continuity elsewhere in your repo. Considering Source Control's only purpose is to track development history, that power should give pause. Rebase absolutely has its place but it shouldn't be used flippantly. Improper rebasing can neuter the ability to accurately git blame or git diff  down the road.

Comment: @DanK I'm not advocating doing anything "improperly". I'm saying that you shouldn't be afraid to do it *properly* in cases like this where it's the obviously correct and obviously beneficial way to provide a useful and accurate history. Don't substitute fear for actually *thinking* about the results (good and bad) of a course of action.